# access head tag in InitializeCulture object reference not an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is there a way to access the head tag from InitializeCulture so I can set the head tag lang attribute. I get object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Request[PostBackEventTarget] != null)
    {
        string controlID = Request[PostBackEventTarget];
        // Request.Form[Request[PostBackEventTarget]].ToString();
        string selectedValue = Request.Form[LanguageDropDownID].ToString();
        if (controlID.Equals(Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")))
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(selectedValue);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedValue);
            Page.Header.Attributes.Add("lang", selectedValue); // error
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string culture = (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
        HtmlHead header = Page.Header as HtmlHead;
        header.Attributes.Add("lang", culture); // error
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

The problem is accessing the Head tag and adding attributes to it
and also why does my head tag output differently to the html tag e.g

```
<html lang="<%= (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture %>" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang='<%= (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture %>' runat="server">
```

output

```
<html lang="fa-IR" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="&lt;%= (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture %>">
```

Comment: maybe a little piece of your sourcecode will give something to elaborate on

Answer (score 0):

Several methods to resolve the issue exist.

First, the direct answer to your question. Use `<%#` in server tags, including HTML tags with `runat="server"`. `<%=` in only for plain HTML markup.

```
<head lang='<%# (HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon).Preferences.Culture %>' runat="server">
```

Second, regarding setting the attribute in `InitializeCulture`... I believe `InitializeCulture` is for setting the current culture for the request, not for the markup. Try a later event, such as, `OnInit` or `OnLoad`.

Lastly, and perhaps most importantly, the HEAD tag doesn't require the `lang` attribute unless different than the HTML tag. The `lang` is inherited from its parent. Only the HTML tag needs the `lang` attribute.